# Who is the female character that's being referred to here?

Tags: star-magi

In *[Crux Magi](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/53107626-crux-magi)*, 4th book of *Star Magi*:

> Bullets slammed into the rocks just next to him. Dain took a few steps forward and spot another trooper. She squeezed a few off, hitting the edge of a the hole more than anything else, kicking up dust. He backed up.
> ~Porsha? Are you there?~ he asked again.

On Page 23, I can’t understand this part

> She squeezed a few off, hitting the edge of a the hole more than anything else, kicking up dust.

Who is "she"? Is it Porsha? He backed up her?

Comment: The natural interpretation of this would be that "she" is the other trooper. Is there context that indicates otherwise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this instance, the 'she' appears to refer to an enemy trooper that Dain has spotted through the hole that's just been created, leading up into the enemy-held building.

Note that Dain is male and Porsha (the only other female mentioned in this passage) at this point is trapped under rubble. Dain also wouldn't 'back off' if it was Porsha shooting since she'd be shooting away from him (e.g into the hole toward the enemy), not toward him.

> Behind him, Dain could hear the sounds of distant footsteps. His squad was approaching. **He scanned the rubble for any sign of Porsha. He couldn’t see her, but he could sense life under the rocks.**

We encounter this trooper (and some of the squad that was defending this building) a few paragraphs later.

> Dain climbed to the highest part of the pile and jumped for the edge
> of the hole. He caught it and hauled himself up. Porsha stood nearby,
> and ***several prone, unmoving bodies lay strewn across the floor***.

Comment: She squeezed a few off bullets?

Comment: @GuilhermeWoolley - Yes. The female trooper saw Dain's head and shot at it, mostly hitting the edge of the hole and shooting a few shots through it that didn't hit anything. Dain moved back ("backed up") so that he wouldn't be hit by the bullets.